# Cron job at specific interval of minutes

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04

I need to run a cron job in linux at 20 minutes interval everyday. The most important thing is, it must be on specifically 10th, 30th and 50th minutes.
I think I need to run 3 cron jobs as :

```
10 * * * * /path_to_script
30 * * * * /path_to_script
50 * * * * /path_to_script
```

Is it possible to meet this requirement using a single cron job ?

Comment: don't forget to vote for answer that answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
10,30,50 * * * * /path_to_script
```

or

```
10/20 * * * * /path_to_script
```

---

Answer (score -1):

aggregate all scripts in one with sleep(1200) time separator

#script

```
#!/bin/bash

./wayto/script1;
sleep(1200);
./wayto/script2;
sleep(1200)
./wayto/script3;
```

and make one job in cron via crontab -e

```
10 * * * * /bin/bash /way/to/script
```